# Get the widgets value out side the actitivty in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In my main activity there are few widgets like edit text,textview,spinner.I want to get these widgets value in the class that is called from the Activity.How could i do this .

Acces all the widgets value from different class that is called by the main activity

```
click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                //Like these i have few more of what i have to get the values 

                Spinner abc = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.abc);
                Spinner xyz = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.xyz);
                Spinner deg = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.deg);

                //This is my class where i want to access all the widgets values and perform some action on that
                GetValue obj = new GetValue();
                obj.getAllData();

            }
            });
```

This is something what i want to do please help me i am not getting how could i do this .What values i have to pass in the function to get the values.Thanks

Comment: so the class which you are calling from an activity is another activity or just simple java class?

Comment: just a simple java class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass activity instance/context in the constructor of another class and then can easily access the widget using `activity.findViewById(R.id.abc);`

Like Suppose you have activity A and want to call class B

```
From Activity A:

B b = new B(this);

In Class B:

class B {

private Activity activity;

public B(Activity _activity){
this.actvity = _activity;

}

now access widget with :
activity.findViewById(R.id.abc);
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you can write an interface and it is implemented by your activity
so that you can do all actions on your widgets in your activity itself but call and input data from your class

Answer (score 0):

Create the class object that store these widget values and then get these values in next class by setter and getter.

```
Class Data {
    public String name;
    public String date;
}
```

From Activity A

```
Data data = new Data();
edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.abc);
data.setName(edittext.getText());
```

From Activity B

```
Data data = new Data();
String name = data.getName();
```